# Android Lint not running Android Studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

One of my project is not running Android lint when I run an inspection. I have reset the inspection settings to default and even tried exporting the settings from a project where lint is running. 
Attached is a picture of the settings and the inspection results that I get. 
Any ideas on how I could get Android Lint running in the project?
[Inspection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8H6n.jpg)

My inspection results
[image]

Comment: Of which version is your android gradle plugin?

Comment: @PavloOstasha 3.6.3 Gradle Version 5.6.4

Comment: did you managed to solve this problem? I have encountered this one too. @SABANTO

Comment: @VanechikSpace don't remember what I did to solve the issue but it was probably something nuclear, because invalidate cache, restarts, and importing settings didn't work. I'll try remember and comment here

Comment: @SABANTO I've noticed that android lint warnings and errors appear in this window when i analyze only one file but when i do it over the whole project they don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try Invalidating Caches / Restart

File --> Invalidate Caches

If it didn't work, try reinstalling Android Studio

Comment: Invalidate Caches and restart worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture, it seems that your lint is working. Probably, you are expecting other lint type errors also but since your project doesn't have those errors, they are not listed here.

Comment: Yes it is running, but I'm not getting results for 'Android' errors, and the errors are there but not showing, hence the question

Comment: Could you please check the following:

1. Does your project have any baseline-lint file in your project main folder?

2. Check lintOptions() in build.gradle, if you have disabled that lint by mistake.

3. Try to switch to the default profile in inspections and see if it helps.


Also, I just wanted to ask how are you so sure that you have 'Android lint' which is not showing up?

Comment: @SonuSourav I have detected that there is no neither baseline-lint file nor lintOptions() in build.gradle. After Adding lintOptions(), baseline-lint file has appeared, but the issue has remained. Swithcing to the default profile also didn't help.